# Can't reuse php class

Tags: php, class

Please bear with me as I'm new to php. I want to reuse the existing methods inside my php class, however I can't find the proper way of including it on another php file because the php class has been used already in one of my php file. So here's the hierarchy of my files:

```
index.php
admin.php

includes
     class.admin.php
     profile.php
```

On `admin.php`, I have no problem including the `class.admin.php` file, I simply do this:

```
require_once("includes/class.admin.php");
$admin= new Admin();
$mail = $_SESSION['admin_mail'];
... then do stuffs here..
```

So here's my call via ajax:

```
function showprofile(){
 $("#show").dialog({ resizable: false, height:200, modal: true,
 var email = "<?php echo $mail; ?>";
  buttons: {
    "Confirm": function() { 
        $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'http://www.xxxxx.com/includes/profile.php', data: 'mail='+ email,
        success:function(msg){ 
        $('#resultmsg').html(msg);
        }});//end ajax      
        $(this).dialog("close");}, 
    Cancel: function() { $(this).dialog("close");}
  }
  });
```

}

I have several ajax functions and it's working fine, I just want to reuse the class.admin so that I won't need to recreate the same method over again..

ajax function is pointing to `profile.php`, how can I reuse the  methods inside my `class.admin`? On `profile.php`, I have this:

```
include("class.admin.php"); //wont work

$profile = new Admin();

$mail = strip_tags(htmlentities($_POST['mail'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));

$text= $profile->getprofile($mail);
echo $text;

require("class.admin.php"); // won't work either
/* calling */ $admin->getprofile($mail); // won't work
/* creating new object as */ $profile = new Admin(); // won't work
```

Kindly make suggestions on how can I use the methods inside the class.

Comment: have you called the class.admin.php in the profile.php page?

Comment: initiate the object of a class before including the profile.php then you could use that object in profile.php

Comment: @arunrc, yes, I tried require("class.admin.php"); but not returning any errors even if I use ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: @Akki - can you show me how? I tried $profile = new Admin(); then echo $profile=getprofile($mail); won't work..

Comment: @bash , In profile.php include the admin class and create a object of that class and use that object

Comment: @user3040610, I did include("class.admin.php"); then create $profile = new Admin(); then echo $profile->getprofile($mail); -does not return anything..

Comment: ...pedantic site-note: [require/include](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.include.php) are statements not functions.

Comment: @bash,check with print_r(get_class_methods($profile));.if methods are empty then check whether you have included the right path.

Comment: Show us your Ajax call, are you POSTing or GETting?

Comment: @user3040610 - nothing happens with print_r(get_class_methods($profile)); no errors returned. how should I call the class? require("class.admin.php") and include("class.admin.php"); won't work.. I'm not sure what the right path is.. and mind that I'm calling profile.php via ajax..

Comment: @bash,share your ajax function and profile.php

Comment: @jylipaa,@user3040610, edited the question above, I'm posting via ajax, it's working fine as I have used several of these, problem is, on another php file, I'm creating the methods again, so I would just like to reuse what I have on the class.admin so it would not be redundant on writing methods over again..

Comment: Your example for profile.php - do you have those lines there in exact shown order? You need to include the class.admin.php before creating instances of Admin. And PHP doesn't remember these between http requests - so you can't "preload" these into memory for future ajax calls. (If i now understood what you try to achieve)

Comment: @jylipaa, edited the question above.  what I'm trying to achieve here is limit the db connection using my class.admin only, and avoid redundant codes/methods if it exists within my class... hope you see my dilemma here..

Answer (score 0):

first include your class in index.php like

```
<?php
    include("admin.class.php");
    /* some stuff */
    $profile = new Admin();

    include("profile.php");
    /* now you can use object $profile in your profile.php */

    $text = $profile->getprofile($mail);
    echo $text;

?>
```

in  your profile.php

```
<?php
    $text = $profile->getprofile($mail);
    echo $text;
?>
```